# Detecting HTML5 Drag And Drop support in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, standards

I'm trying to detect the HTML5 Drag And Drop support in JavaScript. Modernizr seems to not handle this test case.

Comment: For those stepping over the issue still in 2022: Modernizr removed the detection in 2015. Here is what the changelos says: > 11 September 2015 : drop draganddrop detect for reasons [`#1585`](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/1585)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if('draggable' in document.createElement('span')) {
  alert("Drag support detected");
}
```

[You can see a quick demo test using the above check here](http://jsfiddle.net/cDmVF/).

Also, [there's a nice feature detection (not browser detection, yay!) list that's fairly well maintained here](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html) in case you're looking for other HTML5 features as well.

Comment: @gre - If that resolves your issue, make sure to accept an answer by clicking the check mark on th left, same goes for future answers :)  If you are still running into anything please comment so I can help further

Comment: This test may have once been reliable, but it does not appear to be anymore. The linked jsFiddle detects drag support on both Safari (on both iPhone and iPad iOS 8.1.1) and Chrome (v39 on Android).

Comment: @NickCraver, may I ask you to take a look at a drag and drop related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498364/jquery-drag-and-drop-simulation-does-not-work-for-the-last-draggable

Answer (score 14):

Detecting "draggable' in document.createElement('span') seems like a good idea, but in practice it doesn't work.

iOS claims that draggable is in the element but doesn't allow drag and drop. (Reference: [Safari Web Content Guide: Handling Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW19))

IE9 claims that draggable is NOT in the element, but does allow drag and drop. (Reference: my testing HTML5 drag and drop in IE.)

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is a better choice because it doesn't confuse IE. However, it states that HTML5 drag and drop is available on iOS.

Here's how I detect HTML5 drag and drop:

```
var iOS = !!navigator.userAgent.match('iPhone OS') || !!navigator.userAgent.match('iPad');
if (Modernizr.draganddrop && !iOS) {
    HTML5 drag and drop solution
} else if (Modernizr.draganddrop && iOS) {
    iOS drag and drop solution 
} else {
    non-HTML5 drag and drop solution
}
```

Comment: I can speak about the IE-part of your comments. Yes, IE9 and lower can support drag and drop (in a hacky-way) with SPANs via dragDrop() method. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500615/internet-explorer-9-drag-and-drop-dnd). However, it does not support drag and drop to the extent of HTML5. And the question was about HTML5-level support.

Answer (score 11):

This is how it's implemented in Modernizr

```
function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    return ('draggable' in div) || ('ondragstart' in div && 'ondrop' in div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if "dragstart" and "drop" are supported, using the "isEventSupported" method in Modernizr. See [How to detect browser support File API drag n drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518033/how-to-detect-browser-support-file-api-drag-n-drop).