# What animation/function to use for a lineup (user interface)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I'm building a football game and wish to allow my users to build their lineup online, without using tons of javascript.

I would like to have, on the left side, all the players names and positions listed, whilst on the right side are the divs for each lineup position to fill in.

My two options are:

**1) Drag and drop the players to their spot on the lineup**

OR

**2) Click on a player (becomes highlighted) and click on the spot (the name appears in the lineup and the highlight disappears in the left list)**

Which option is the simplest to use AND mostly, do you have any script example for the animation you suggest (say for 2 players) that I could use as a model (I have Jquery installed on the server by the way)? Most of the drag-and-drop scripts I found online were way too complicated and heavy for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion drag and drop would be nicer to use from the perspective of a user. However that's just my opinion.

If you would like to go with drag and drop, look into [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much you want to take advantage of built-in DnD functionality, but for a solution that is portable you could look at something like this page, but I would change it so that when you click on the player it adds the `mousemove` event handler, and on `mouseup` this would be removed.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Event/MouseDragandDrop.htm

You could also look at using the `Drag and Drop` API for browsers that support it, which would be simpler.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dragdrop/drag_and_drop

But, if you want to go with JQuery's solution that would also be simple.

Based on my response DnD would be the best option for the UI, I believe, but it doesn't have to be complicated to implement, I gave you three options. Personally I with go with a mix of the first two.

Comment: I'll look at the second option, seems interesting, although I hope that function works in Firefox, GC, Safari and IE9 at the least (the link is Mozilla's developper's page, that's why i'm sceptical). For earlier IE versions I don't care..

Comment: Look here for browser support (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)) and for a question on IE9 and DnD API (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500615/internet-explorer-9-drag-and-drop-dnd)