# Event ondragstart is no longer triggered in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-9

I've implemented [HTML5 drag and drop](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/dnd.html) on DIVs. It works great in all browsers, including IE8. But ever since IE9 was released, it not longer works. The ondragstart event does not get triggered. Here is my code, using jQuery:

```
$('#mydiv')
   .bind('selectstart', function(e) {
        // Prevent text selection
        return false;
    })
    .bind('dragstart', function(e) {
        console.log('dragstart');
    })
    .bind('drag', function(e) {
        console.log('drag');
    })
    .bind('dragend', function(e) {
        console.log('dragend');
    });
```

and the HTML

```
<div draggable="true">DnD this thing!</div>
```

Comment: is that a typo ? but your div has no `id="mydiv"`

Answer (score 6):

I'm betting that didn't work in IE8, because neither IE8 or IE9 fully support HTML5 drag and drop, that's only been added in [IE10 Developer Preview 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh272905#_HTML5DragDrop).  The HTML5 API is based on the implementation of drag and drop in IE5, but there are some differences.  Most pertinently, IE9 and before don't support the `draggable` attribute on elements - the only things that can be dragged in IE9 are things which are draggable by default: text selections, links and images.

So for it to work in IE9 (or IE8) you need to add a link into your HTML (and that link must have an `href`):

```
<div id="mydiv"><a draggable="true" href="#">DnD this thing!</a></div>
```

Your JavaScript should then work as expected with a few slight modifications:

```
$('#mydiv')
   .bind('selectstart', function(e) {
        // Prevent text selection
        return false;
    })
    .bind('dragstart', function(e) {
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", $(e.target).closest('div').attr('id'));
        console.log('dragstart');
    })
    .bind('drag', function(e) {
        console.log('drag');
    })
    .bind('dragend', function(e) {
        console.log('dragend');
    })
    .bind('click', function(e) {
        return false;
    });
```

[Here's an example which I've tested in Firefox and IE9](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/UhCny/2/).

Comment: Here is a workaround to enable DnD other element than links, images and text selections: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8986075/237209