# jQuery draggable panels broken in IE 9 w/out errors

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, draggable

Please take a look at this demo of collapsible, drag n drop panels w/ jQuery: http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/drag-drop-panels/.

It works fine in everything, including IE 7 and 8, except IE 9 (and shows no errors in IE 9 console).  Can anyone figure out what the problem is?  No one on the host site and tutorial seems to have an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500615/internet-explorer-9-drag-and-drop-dnd - see if any of these solutions help

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-sortable-and-draggable-do-not-work-in-ie9 - this also should help

Comment: Change your version of jQuery from 1.3.2 and this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know what is the problem but I see you are using a old jquery (1.3) and jquery ui (1.7) librarys.

Jquery current release is 1.7.1: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/21/jquery-1-7-1-released/

Jquery ui current release is 1.8.18: http://jqueryui.com/download

Try change the librarys