# HTML drag and drop in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I tried drag and drop in HTML. It is working good in all browsers except IE9 (no need to work on lower than IE9). ondrop event is not triggered in IE9.

any help? here is my code.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/ASKte/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500615/internet-explorer-9-drag-and-drop-dnd

Comment: @CodeJack, i have seen it already. There is no accepted solution. And i tried to replace <div> with <a> as suggested there. still no use.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=drag See the notes for IE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'll work if you replace `div` with `a` tags.  However there are a couple of other changes you ought to make, firstly make sure that the `a` tags aren't clickable links by returning `false` in the `onclick` event:

```
<a class="div123" href="#" draggable="true"
 ondragstart="handleDragStart(event)"
 ondrop="handleDrop(event)"
 ondragover="dragoveHandler(event)"
 onclick="return false;">
    HTML5 drag and drop
</a>
```

Secondly, IE9 doesn't accept parameters of `text/plain` in `setData`, use `Text` instead or add the data inside of a `try...catch`.  Also, you should make sure the data you're adding is actually text:

```
e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", "" + $(e.target).index());
```

Finally your `handleDrop` function needs to `preventDefault`/`return false` because otherwise the default action for dropping a link (an `a` element`) is to navigate to the dropped URL:

```
function handleDrop(e) {
    alert($(e.target).index());
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Stops redirect.
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Here is a jsFiddle of your code which will work in IE9](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/ASKte/4/).