# HTML5 Drag and Drop upload is not working on below the version IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the HTML5 DND file uploading http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload but it is not working in the below the version IE 10

Webpage error details in IE browsers

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; BTRS124829; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Wed, 2 Jan 2013 06:17:02 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 57
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the previous answers, its not just about `FileReader`.
Drag and Drop cannot be used **perfectly** in versions less than IE10. Even IE9 has some problems, let be IE8.

The browser should also support the DnD API

Check this link to another answer - [**Internet Explorer 9 Drag and Drop (DnD)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500615/internet-explorer-9-drag-and-drop-dnd)

Check my application that allows drag drop of image files from your OS in to the browser:
[**HTML-5-DD**](http://omshankar.kodingen.com/exp/backbone-html5-dd/) - BackboneJS

It has 2 parts:
1. HTML5 Drag drop, that allows drag drop from OS to Browser
2. `FileReader` API that helps reading the image files as DataURI and appending the images

If your browser does not support Drag Drop, you won't be able to drag drop images in a way that can be understood by `JavaScript`.

Conclusion: `FileReader` is not the main feature that IE needs to suport for your scenario, its also and importantly the **Drag Drop**

Comment: @Karthik, Happy new year. Also, here's a link to a better tutorial - Native HTML5 Drag Drop - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Answer (score 1):

This is because `HTML5` uses `File API & FileReader API` which are not supported in IE whose versions are below 10.

Check the compatibility list [here](http://caniuse.com/filereader)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks is any other DND upload available with working in ie versions?

Comment: you can use flash uploaders like `uploadifive` for dnd. [demos](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) [docs](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/)

Comment: Its not just the **`FileReader API`**, its also the support for HTML5 Drag and Drop itself