# Dart HTML5 Drag and Drop in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-9, dart

I'm trying to implement **HTML5 Drag and Drop with Dart**. To get Drag and Drop working in **IE9 with elements other than links and images**, I use a workaround (see [Internet Explorer 9 Drag and Drop (DnD)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8986075/862411) and [this live example](http://marakana.com/s/post/1071/html5_drag_n_drop_api#try2)).

I use the following code in Dart:

```dart
/**
 * Workaround to enable drag-and-drop elements other than links and images in
 * Internet Explorer 9.
 */
void _enableIE9drag(Element element) {     
  element.onSelectStart.listen((MouseEvent event) {
    // Prevent selection of text.
    event.preventDefault();

    // This should be a native call to dragDrop()
    element.dragDrop();
  });
}
```

The call to `element.dragDrop()` should be a native JavaScript call for IE9. Instead `dart2js` compiles the method call to `dragDrop$0()`.

If I manually edit the generated js output and remove  the `$0`, everything works as it should in IE9.

So, **how can I make a call to the native `dragDrop()` javascript function of IE9?**

---

### Edit

As suggested by Greg I've opened [bug 10837](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10837) in the hopes that we could get rid of this browser inconsistency withing `dart:html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by adding a little javascript to my main HTML filer (please tell me if you have a better idea):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- some stuff -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function callDragDrop(el) {
        el.dragDrop();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- some stuff -->
  </body>
 </html>
```

Now I can call this function with Darts `js-interop`:

```dart
/**
 * Workaround to enable drag-and-drop elements other than links and images in
 * Internet Explorer 9.
 */
void _enableIE9drag(Element element) {
  if (element.draggable == null) {
    // HTML5 draggable support is not available --> try to use workaround.

    element.onSelectStart.listen((MouseEvent event) {
      // Prevent selection of text.
      event.preventDefault();

      // Use the javascript function to call the native dragDrop() of element
      js.context.callDragDrop(element);
    });
  }
}
```

### Edit

Created a helper library to use [HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://code.makery.ch/dart/html5-drag-and-drop) in Dart.

Comment: Unfortunately the JS interop package adds a lot of overhead to the generated js code - so use with care. Ideally Dart should be able to solve these type of cross browser inconsistencies within dart:html. I'd suggest filing a bug. http://dartbug.com/

Comment: @Greg: You're right. Here is [Issue 10837](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10837)

Comment: FWIW - I've written a few different drag and drop interactions in javascript. I.e. moving DOM elements to targets. I initially used native dnd, but found inconsistencies with how the overlay images are drawn (and other things I forget). In the end I rewrote it just using DOM and mouse events. This was the only way I could get the exact control that I needed. I think this is how the circles drag and drop works in g+.

Comment: Almost gave up on trying to implement drag images cross-browser... But then found a solution with SVG images that works. I've included a link in the answer above to a Dart library I created to make using HTML5 Drag and Drop more comfortble.

Comment: @Greg: Now there is touch event support in [HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://edu.makery.ch/projects/dart-html5-drag-and-drop/) library.

Answer (score 0):

dragDrop() is not a method in the Dart [Element](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Element.html) class so you can't call it.

Have you tried using the drag and drop events defined on the [Element](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Element.html) class? Dart provides shims to make these work in IE9.

If you can't get this to work cross browser using Dart's drag and drop api then you should file a bug.

Comment: The drag and drop events of Element do work in IE9 but only with *image* and *link* tags. The workaround with calling `dragDrop()` would make it possible to drag other elements like *divs*.

Comment: Ah - right I thought you were trying to do File drag and drop. For dragging div's around I just handle mouse events, and use css transform translate. The native drag and drop api's behave differently across browsers.