# How to detect browser support File API drag n drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fileapi

I like to add a background on a div only for browsers which support drag & drop for files

I don't like to use modernizr though, just a one line script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just copy required parts from Modernizr?

```
var isEventSupported = (function() {

      var TAGNAMES = {
        'select': 'input', 'change': 'input',
        'submit': 'form', 'reset': 'form',
        'error': 'img', 'load': 'img', 'abort': 'img'
      };

      function isEventSupported( eventName, element ) {

        element = element || document.createElement(TAGNAMES[eventName] || 'div');
        eventName = 'on' + eventName;

        // When using `setAttribute`, IE skips "unload", WebKit skips "unload" and "resize", whereas `in` "catches" those
        var isSupported = eventName in element;

        if ( !isSupported ) {
          // If it has no `setAttribute` (i.e. doesn't implement Node interface), try generic element
          if ( !element.setAttribute ) {
            element = document.createElement('div');
          }
          if ( element.setAttribute && element.removeAttribute ) {
            element.setAttribute(eventName, '');
            isSupported = typeof element[eventName] == 'function';

            // If property was created, "remove it" (by setting value to `undefined`)
            if ( typeof element[eventName] != 'undefined' ) {
              element[eventName] = undefined;
            }
            element.removeAttribute(eventName);
          }
        }

        element = null;
        return isSupported;
      }
      return isEventSupported;
    })();
```

Usage:

```
if (isEventSupported('dragstart') && isEventSupported('drop')) {
  ...
}
```

And for File API:

```
var isFileAPIEnabled = function() {
  return !!window.FileReader;
};
```

Comment: Will not work. You cant just take one function from framework :) You need at least `is` function definition

Comment: Thanks anton_byrna!

Unfortunately Chrome supports it and alert false!?!

Comment: Strangely, I check in Chrome 12.0.742.112 for 'dragstart' and 'drop' it return true. isFileAPIEnabled() return true;

Comment: Nevermind - have an old version of chrome. I marked this question as answered

Thanks!

Comment: Supporting the 'drop' event doesn't mean it supports FILE dropping. IE 8 supports the 'drop' event.

Comment: Also - Safari users would be denied as `return !!window.FileReader` will return false in Safari 5, despite file drag and drop being readily supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`return 'draggable' in document.createElement('span') && typeof(window.FileReader) != 'undefined';`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with Modernizr at all, you can just replicate what it does for drag'n'drop detection:

```
var supportsDragAndDrop = function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    return ('draggable' in div) || ('ondragstart' in div && 'ondrop' in div);
}
```

Got it from Modernizr GitHub repository:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/draganddrop.js

Answer (score 0):

checkout  **modernizr** source code technique for the HTML5 drag and drop detection https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/draganddrop.js

Answer (score 0):

except this seems to incorrectly detect iOS as supporting drag and drop

Comment: I've found this as well, though you should be putting it as a comment on the answer you're referring to instead of its own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why everybody needs to create a new element to check this. I think it's enough to just check that the body element supports dragging events and that the browser supports the File API

```
supportsDragAndDrop(){
   body = document.body
   return ("draggable" in body || ("ondragstart" in body && "ondrop" in body)) 
        && window.FormData && window.FileReader
}
```