# Detect browser drag and drop compatibility by Blueimp jQuery-File-Upload API

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Is it possible to detect browser drag and drop compatibility by using Blueimp File Upload API or its function/variable? Or this plugin just waiting for actual drag event from browser and does not analyze its capabilities?

This would be useful to hide drop zone instuctions (like "drug files here") from the old browser user.

There are independent methods proposed in this answers: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18890590/1056384 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743796

For the file drag it is also good to cheсk window.FileReader:

```
return 'draggable' in document.createElement('span') && typeof(window.FileReader) != 'undefined';
```