# How can I detect if browser is capable to receive files via drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I know how to detect drag&drop API, I know how to detect `FileReader` and `FileList` feature. The problem is that modern mobile browsers can handle all these things, but they obviously do not allow dropping files to the page.

I have an area on a page where user can drop files, and I want to hide this area on devices that do not support this.

Comment: I think that "they obviously do not allow dropping files to the page" part should go after the word "devices" to make more sense ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Modernizr issue https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/57 about that. The only way for now is to detect mobile devices by `navigator.userAgent`.

Answer (score -2):

Use library like Modernizr, to detect wide variety of html5 features.

**UPDATE:**

To check to make sure that the browser supports the HTML5 FileReader. Assuming it does, code is attached to the window's onload() event so that the drop element is declared after the page has finished loading. To enable a DIV to accept dropped items, we have to cancel the default behavior for the 'dragover' and 'dragenter' events:

```
if(window.FileReader) {
```

**Complete drag and drop from desktop to browser tutorial at** : http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/drag-files-into-the-browser-from-the-desktop-HTML5.html#fbid=rxWgmrkH83W

To detect drag and drop support use drag and drop property like this:

```
if(Modernizr.draganddrop) {
```

If you want to do this in **pure javascript** ( from Modernizr source code) :

```
var isEventSupported = (function() {

      var TAGNAMES = {
        'select': 'input', 'change': 'input',
        'submit': 'form', 'reset': 'form',
        'error': 'img', 'load': 'img', 'abort': 'img'
      };

      function isEventSupported( eventName, element ) {

        element = element || document.createElement(TAGNAMES[eventName] || 'div');
        eventName = 'on' + eventName;

        // When using `setAttribute`, IE skips "unload", WebKit skips "unload" and "resize", whereas `in` "catches" those
        var isSupported = eventName in element;

        if ( !isSupported ) {
          // If it has no `setAttribute` (i.e. doesn't implement Node interface), try generic element
          if ( !element.setAttribute ) {
            element = document.createElement('div');
          }
          if ( element.setAttribute && element.removeAttribute ) {
            element.setAttribute(eventName, '');
            isSupported = typeof element[eventName] == 'function';

            // If property was created, "remove it" (by setting value to `undefined`)
            if ( typeof element[eventName] != 'undefined' ) {
              element[eventName] = undefined;
            }
            element.removeAttribute(eventName);
          }
        }

        element = null;
        return isSupported;
      }
      return isEventSupported;
    })();
```

Usage:

```
if (isEventSupported('dragstart') && isEventSupported('drop')) {
  ...
}
```

And for File API:

```
var isFileAPIEnabled = function() {
  return !!window.FileReader;
};
```

**Reference:**

1. http://modernizr.com/docs/
2. [Already answered Stack Overflow Question how-to-detect-browser-support-file-api-drag-n-drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518033/how-to-detect-browser-support-file-api-drag-n-drop)

Comment: I know how to detect drag&drop API, I know how to detect FileReader and FileList feature. The problem is that modern mobile browsers can handle all these things, but they obviously do not allow dropping files to the page.

Comment: @homm You need to check for window.FilReader and implement the drag and drop, Check http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/drag-files-into-the-browser-from-the-desktop-HTML5.html once

Comment: `FileReader` does not answers the question "Is browser capable to receive files via drag and drop". At least mobile Safari has `FileReader` and Drag&Drop APIs, but does not allows to receive files via drag and drop.