# How to check for IE Drag & Drop support of any element

Tags: internet-explorer, html, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to check if a user agent supports drag & drop of a particular element (div, tr,...)?

I've got a table with draggable table rows, which works fine in Chrome. But since Internet Explorer (up to version 9) only supports dragging of images and links (and a few others), I wanted to give it a little anchor drag handle inside the table row instead. My code looks something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr draggable="true">
        <td><a class="drag-handle"></a> Hello World</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$('tr[draggable]').each(function() {
    // Remove draggable="true" from <tr>
    $(this).attr('draggable', '');
    // Add draggable="true" to <a class="drag-handle">
    $(this).find('.drag-handle').attr('draggable', 'true');
});
```

Obviously, there is a lot more to do to actually make this work, but you get the gist: giving the user a drag thingy if their client doesn't support dragging of a  (IE<10).

Now i want to do the replacement *only* if the user's client doesn't support dragging of table rows. Is there any known feature detection for that?

Comment: The answers to this question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856262/detecting-html5-drag-and-drop-support-in-javascript

Comment: http://jqueryui.com and use this: `$(this).removeAttr('draggable');` insted of this: `$(this).attr('draggable', '');` http://jsfiddle.net/k6EDZ/ http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: Whenever you're looking for code to test browser support, a good place to check is [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). It includes tests for this and many other features.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Obviously, I looked at Modernizr first, but it checks only if the browser has _any_ DND support. So IE gets a thumbs up from Modernizr, even though it doesn't support dragging of the elements I've mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Detecting HTML5 Drag And Drop support in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856262/detecting-html5-drag-and-drop-support-in-javascript):

```
if('draggable' in document.createElement('span')) {
    alert("Drag support detected");
}
```

Thanks to [Mark Rhodes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509619/mark-rhodes) for the tip! Also thanks to [micha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001563/micha) for pointing out my jQuery error (`removeAttr('draggable')` instead of `attr('draggable')`).

Comment: This reports as true in IE10.