# html5 dragover not working in IE 5.5 to IE 8

Tags: html

I know html5 dragover is not supported by IE except IE 9. I am copy pasting my js file code and it's working with Chrome / Mozilla with a image drag and drop but not working in IE. I need a solution that work on all browsers. For example remove dragover function from js and let me know how I can give a image path (hard coded) or using simple file upload. Thanks and awaiting for the response.

```
    jQuery(function($) {
    var sourceImg = $('<img>')[0],
    description = $('#description'),
    sourceCanvas = $('#source')[0],
    sourceCtx = sourceCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    compressedCanvas = $('#compressed')[0],
    compressedCtx = compressedCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    compressedOverlayCanvas = $('#compressedOverlay')[0],
    compressedOverlayCtx = compressedOverlayCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    all = $('canvas'),
    quality = 88,
    scale = 10;

function analyzeImage(image){
    all.attr('width', image.width);
    all.attr('height', image.height);
    sourceCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    var sourceData = sourceCtx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height),
        compressed = $('<img>');
    $('<img>')
        .on('load', function() {
            compressedCtx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            var compressedData = compressedCtx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height),
                data0 = sourceData.data,
                data1 = compressedData.data;

            for(var i = 0, l = data0.length; i < l; i+=4) {
                for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    var error = Math.abs(data0[i+j]-data1[i+j]);
                    data0[i+j] = error*scale;
                }
            }
            compressedCtx.putImageData(sourceData, 0, 0);
            compressedOverlayCtx.drawImage(compressedCanvas, 0, 0);
            $('#description').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#results').show();
        }).attr('src', sourceCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality*0.01)); 
}

$('html')
    .on('dragover', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); return false;})
    .on('drop', function(e) {
        var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
            var file = files[0];
            if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined" && file.type.indexOf("image") != -1) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                // Note: addEventListener doesn't work in Google Chrome for this event
                reader.onload = function (evt) {
                    sourceImg.src = evt.target.result;
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

$('input').on('change', function() {
        $(this).next('.value').text($(this).val());
        quality = document.forms[0].quality.value * 1;
        scale = document.forms[0].scale.value * 1;
        if(sourceImg.src) analyzeImage(sourceImg);
    }).change();

$(sourceImg)
    .on('error', function () { alert('something went wrong when loading the image'); })
    .on('load', function () {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'iela', 'imageAnalyzed']);
        analyzeImage(sourceImg);
    });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Actually the Native Drag and Drop has been supported by Internet Explorer since version 5.5 or 6. It was specified by Microsoft in 1999. HTML5 took over the API as is (unfortunately). The two links that will give you a solid explanation of how to use Native drag and drop are:

- for background information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537658%28VS.85%29.aspx
- for a crossbrowser solution: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/01/10/cross-browser-html5-drag-and-drop/

I wrote a german article on HTML5 drag and drop for a German web magazine 1.5 years ago. I created a crossbrowser demo. The source code is on github, but commented in german: https://raw.github.com/tjunghans/DnD-Webstandards/master/public/article-beispiel.html

My suggestion is to use a library for drag and drop such as http://jqueryui.com/draggable/. It's much easier and will give you less headaches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you plz tell me can i get a file path in string from html5 dragover ??

Comment: Could you provide html, css, javascript and any images I may need, preferably in a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 0):

You can make IE 8 and lower mimic HTML5 drag and drop. When you have done that, then you can use HTML5 drag and drop events Look at this answer to a post (ignore the question's title when the page opens):

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/15867951/178550](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500615/internet-explorer-9-drag-and-drop-dnds)

In essence, you need the listen for "selectStart" event and call dragDrop() function to get thing started. I recommend you use Modernizr so that IE 9 and above, Opera, Chrome and FireFox who support HTML 5 drag and drop do not need this workaround do not try to use it. Here a question/answers post about drag and drop Modernizr:

[Detecting HTML5 Drag And Drop support in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856262/detecting-html5-drag-and-drop-support-in-javascript)