# Detect drag&drop support on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, feature-detection

[Caniuse says](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop) that Firefox for Android (v63) does not support drag&drop. Which is understandable since drag&drop doesn't make much sense on a single-app mobile screen. But the corresponding events are defined on several elements.

How can I detect this "not supported"?

I want to display a message like "click to choose files or drag them here" but obviously leave out the drag part if it's pointless.

```
alert("alert is supported");
if ("ondrop" in document)
    alert("document.ondrop is defined");
```

`document` can be replaced with a `<div>` or `<input type=file>` element. Same result. Firefox 64 on Windows & Android. I'm also interested in a Chrome solution (should work everywhere).

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856262/detecting-html5-drag-and-drop-support-in-javascript) has been asked 9 years ago and its answers were commented as being outdated 5 years ago. The answers don't solve my question and also don't cover Android in any way (I have nothing to do with iOS and can't test that).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting HTML5 Drag And Drop support in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856262/detecting-html5-drag-and-drop-support-in-javascript)

Comment: No, that code says my Firefox would support drag&drop. Is Caniuse wrong? Anyway, how can I detect this if not by a feature-detection? Test for Android?

Comment: You are asking a duplicate question. If the other question is wrong than post a better answer, but don't expect people to answer the same thing twice just because you have a different use case.

Comment: Haha, you're funny! I am asking, how do you think I can post an answer? Alright, then it's a duplicate. Oh, and can you please tell me how I can revive the old question to get users to post new and working answers again? One of the biggest annoyances of Stack Overflow is outdating and then always-to-be-true content. That question is 9 years old, and 5 years ago, its answers were considered outdated. My problem exists *now*. Maybe deleting old questions would be good, so they can be asked again without being rejected as duplicates of outdated information.

Comment: Duplicates are a community voted action. Until this is closed as a duplicate it will remain open. If you get answers or not is really a different topic of discussion. Higher quality questions tend to get better activity, but some questions are just difficult to answer. There are a lot of outdated old questions. You can update your question to reflect why it's not a duplicate or why the duplicate is not applicable. I can not retract a vote unless the question has been edited.